# Logical error in loop resulting in unwanted output

Tags: java, loops, logic

I am not sure how to fix this.

```
 List<Temporary> getTemporaryList = getTemporary();
      Map<Integer, Set<Attribute>> attributeOrderMap = attributeOrderMap(getTemporaryList);
      Map<Integer, Set<OrderSample>> sampleOrderMap = sampleOrderMap(getTemporaryList);

      Set<OrderSample> temporaryOrderSampleSet = Sets.newHashSet();
      java.util.ListIterator<Order> it = orders.listIterator();
      List<Order> finalOrder = Lists.newArrayList();

for (Order order : orders) {
         temporaryOrderSampleSet.clear();
         if (sampleOrderMap.containsKey((order.getId()))) {
            Set<OrderSample> samples = sampleOrderMap.get(order.getId());

            for (OrderSample orderSample : samples) {
               Set<Attribute> attributes = attributeOrderMap.get(order.getId());
               orderSample.setAttributes(attributes);
               temporaryOrderSampleSet.add(orderSample);
               order.setSample(temporaryOrderSampleSet);
               finalOrder.add(order);
            }
         }
      }
```

I have a list of orders. 1000 orders. I have a set of samples and a set of attributes. For the first attribute i want to put it in the first sample and then put it in the first order. Then the same for the second attribute, put it in the second sample then put that sample in the second order.

So my list would look something like the following

Attribute1 --> sample1 --> Order1

Attribute2 --> sample2 --> Order2

Attribute3 --> sample3 --> Order3

Attribute4 --> sample4 --> Order4

My current code keeps adding on samples again and again. So my first list starts out small, then my second one is bigger since it contains everything from the first list and second list, then third is even bigger etc. I am stuck and dont know what to do.

Comment: It seems that you wanted to say `temporaryOrderSampleSet.clear();` in the `for (OrderSample orderSample : samples)` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `temporaryOrderSampleSet` inside the `for` loop.

```
for (Order order : orders) {
         Set<OrderSample> temporaryOrderSampleSet = Sets.newHashSet();
         if (sampleOrderMap.containsKey((order.getId()))) {
```

Otherwise, you put the **same** list over and over again, and clear it so only last iteration sets it value.

Another issue:

```
order.setSample(temporaryOrderSampleSet);
```

can be set outside the inner for loop. In your code you just override the value again and again.

Comment: so I would declare the temporaryOrderSampleSet inside the loop as opposed to outside the loop?

Comment: Yes. This way every order will get its **own** samples.

Comment: I still get a list that grows everytime

Comment: Which list is growing?

Comment: just trying ur another issue now to see if it work,compiling as of now

Comment: for (Order order : orders) {
   Set<OrderSample> temporaryOrderSampleSet = Sets.newHashSet();
         if (sampleOrderMap.containsKey((order.getId()))) {
            Set<OrderSample> samples = sampleOrderMap.get(order.getId());
            order.setSample(temporaryOrderSampleSet);
            for (OrderSample orderSample : samples) {
               Set<Attribute> attributes = attributeOrderMap.get(order.getId());
               orderSample.setAttributes(attributes);
               temporaryOrderSampleSet.add(orderSample);
               finalOrder.add(order);
            }
         }
      }

Comment: this keeps giving me orders that increase in length everytime, they just keep getting samples added onto it

Comment: I dont understand which list is growing.

Comment: list #1 = Attribute1 --> sample1 --> Order1

list #2 = Attribute2 --> sample2 --> Order2

list #3 Attribute3 --> sample3 --> Order3

list #4 Attribute4 --> sample4 --> Order4

list#2 contains list number1, list#3 contains lists 1 and 2 looped over multiple times, list#4 contains lists #1 2 3 also looped through multiple times

Comment: You can move Set<OrderSample> temporaryOrderSampleSet = Sets.newHashSet(); inside the inner for

Comment: now I do not get any samples in the first run of the loop, but i do in the second run of it, so i get an empty set everytime it runs, also it still adds on everything to the order#2 order#3 etc. its smaller than before but its still there

Comment: can you tell me which **JAVA** list is getting all the elements? where is the add method that adds to much data to the list?

Comment: i am returning finalOrder list, and that is getting outputted, so essentially each order is being outputted, so  literally in the form of order#1 which contains sample#1 and attribute#1 then order #2 which contains sample#2 and attribute #2, i am doing a print statement on each finalOrder, so in my most inner loop i have system.println(finalOrder);